# Why connect cells in parallel?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Say there is a circuit with two $1.5\ V$ cells and a $100 \ \Omega$ resistor.

If you connect two cells in series, then the total emf is $3\ V$. And the current will be $3/100 = 0.03\ A$ (Using $V = IR$):

[image]

If you have the cells in parallel, then the total emf is $1.5\ V$, as the terminals of the cells are electrically at the same point. So the current will only be $0.015\ A$:
[image]

But if you just had one $1.5\ V$ cell, so the total emf is again $1.5\ V$. The current will still be $0.015\ A$.
[image]

So what benefit does adding a second cell have? The emf and the current is the same no matter if you use $2$ cells in parallel or just one cell.

I'm assuming that all the cells are identical, and internal resistance is negligible.

Comment: When do the batteries in the various circuits you draw run out of juice? What is the maximum current that each battery configuration can supply? In both cases remember that you have to use real--not idealized--batteries in your real projects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Real batteries have a finite energy storage capacity. Adding additional cells adds additional capacity (this is why I would add them, you haven't really specified any context so it's hard to say what you are looking for).

Also, it's worth noting:

> I'm assuming that all the cells are identical, and internal resistance is negligible.

This is an important assumption. In a real circuit, you would lose some power ($I^2R$) to the internal resistance of the battery. You can reduce this power loss by adding cells, reducing the current each cell provides.

Comment: So by having the cells in parallel, and having less current though each cell, you minimise the power wastage by the internal resistance?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by energy capacity? Do you mean it will take longer for two cells in parallel to run out, compared to 2 cells in series?

Comment: @Jonathan. Yes, less current from each cell will reduce the amount of power lost to the internal resistance. If you halve the current, you lose 1/4 as much power (assuming linear internal resistance approximation). With 2 cells, this means the power loss (in both cells together) is 1/2 as much as one cell.

Comment: @Jonathan. By energy capacity, I just mean that the batteries will run out. Adding cells in parallel keeps the terminal voltage the same (as in your analysis) and adds energy storage capacity. I am comparing two cells in parallel to one cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna **increase** current capacity or current , connect cells in parallel.
If you wanna **increase** voltage ,  connect cells in series.

for example: you have two cells each with ***1.5V , 1A*** rating , so:

If you have concern with increasing voltage, connect cells in series hence getting a battery of rating ***3V , 1A***.

If you have concern with increasing current(mA) or current capacity(mAh), connect cells in parallel hence getting a battery of rating ***1.5V , 2A***.

Comment: As OP points out, connecting batteries in parallel does **not** increase the current.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the current in the circuit, more and more cells are connected in the circuit. cells in parallel reduces the total resistance of the circuit.